# Fourier transform on trig wave

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

Find the fourier transform for signal in this picture (sorry for the bad quality)
[image]

Could it be done like this? The signal is a sum of two triangular waves that are each delayed.
 $$x(t)=A\Lambda\left( \frac{t+T/2}{T}\right)-A\Lambda\left( \frac{t-T/2}{T}\right)$$
And the fourier transform for delayed signal $F\{x(t+t_d)\}=X(f)\cdot e^{-i2\pi ft_d}$. And the fourier transform for triangular pulse is defined $F\{ \Lambda(t/T)\}=T
 \operatorname{sinc}^2(\pi fT)  $
\begin{align}
F\{x(t)\}&=AT \operatorname{sinc}^2(\pi fT)\cdot e^{-i2\pi f (-\frac{T}{2})} -AT \operatorname{sinc}^2(\pi fT)\cdot e^{-i 2 \pi f \frac T2} \\
&=AT \operatorname{sinc}^2(\pi fT)\cdot (e^{i\pi f T} - e^{-i \pi f T}) \\
&=AT \operatorname{sinc}^2(\pi fT)\cdot2i\sin(\pi f T)
\end{align}

Is this solution valid?

Comment: Absolutely. 15 characters are required in a comment.

Comment: Okey nice! I first tried to use time derivative properties of F-transform, but I figured it would be easier to do like this :)

Answer (score 0):

Use differentiation property twice

Differentiate $x(t)$ two times thus it will get converted into impulses

$$\frac{d^2x(t)}{dt^2} = \frac{2A}{T} \delta(t+T)- \frac{4A}{T} \delta(t+\frac{T}{2}) +\frac{4A}{T} \delta(t-\frac{T}{2}) -\frac{2A}{T} \delta(t-T)$$

Now take fourier transform on both sides

$$(j\omega)^2 X(\omega) = \frac{2A}{T} e^{-\omega T}- \frac{4A}{T} e^{-\omega\frac{T}{2}} +\frac{4A}{T} e^{\omega\frac{T}{2}} -\frac{2A}{T} e^{\omega T} $$